# Ajax xml not going into success

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I am trying to access the book.xml file which is in same folder as other files, everything is perfect, but the ajax function wont go into success. [object object] error is being showed.
its a very simple xml. I generally do it via a php file. but i have to do it directly this time. i used dataType = "xml". seems to be a problem in that may be. anyway, please help

**the html code:**

```
<body>

<h2>Hello there, ajax example is loading:</h2>
<div class="row container">

<button class="btn" onclick="gettingdata();">Get data from XML</button>

<hr>

<div class="data">

<table id="datatable">
<tbody>
  <tr>
    <th>Book name</th>
    <th>Author</th>
    <th>year</th>
    <th>price</th>
  </tr>

  </tbody>
</table>

</div>


</div>

</body>
```

**the js code:**

```
$.ajax({

            type: 'GET',
            url: 'books.xml',
            dataType: 'xml',
            success: function(result) {
                alert("into");

                $(result).find('book').each(function() {

                    $('.datatable tbody').append(
                        '<tr>' +
                            '<td>' +
                                $(this).find('title').text() + '</td> ' +
                            '<td>' +
                                $(this).find('author').text() + '</td> ' +
                            '<td>' +
                                $(this).find('year').text() + '</td> ' +
                            '<td>' +    
                                $(this).find('price').text() + '</td> ' +   
                        '</tr>');
                });
            },
            error: function (textStatus, errorThrown) {
                alert(''+textStatus+errorThrown);
            },
            complete: function(){
                alert("done");
            }
        });
```

Comment: Where did you put your file books.xml

Answer (score 1):

(**Reason for your ajax call fail**)Your code is working fine just put your `books.xml` on correct location . Also data in xml file should be valid.

And change

```
 $('.datatable tbody').append
```

to

```
 $('#datatable tbody').append
```

I tried your code on my system. It was working fine. Just make above changes.

Comment: no dude, i tried what you told, i copied books.xml, and placed in all folders possible to see it work. but no use. i changed the .datatable to #datatable though. problem is the success part of ajax is not executing.

Comment: Can you add your folder structure?

Answer (score 0):

this is the xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

`<bookstore>`

```
<book category="cooking">
<title lang="en">Everyday Italian</title>
<author>Giada De Laurentiis</author>
<year>2005</year>
<price>30.00</price>
</book>

<book category="children">
<title lang="en">Harry Potter</title>
<author>J K. Rowling</author>
<year>2005</year>
<price>29.99</price>
</book>

<book category="web">
<title lang="en">XQuery Kick Start</title>
<author>James McGovern</author>
<year>2003</year>
<price>49.99</price>
</book>

<book category="web" cover="paperback">
<title lang="en">Learning XML</title>
<author>Erik T. Ray</author>
<year>2003</year>
<price>39.95</price>
</book>

</bookstore>
```